# Getting big objects with FreeMarker

Tags: java, reflection, freemarker

I think it would be really great, if template designer would be able to access all the fields he wants from the given object. So in java instead of:

```
Map<String, Object> fields = new HashMap<>();
fields.add("x", unit.getX());
fields.add("y", unit.getY());
fields.add("z", unit.getZ());
Map<String, Object> dataModel = new HashMap<>();
dataModel.put("unit", fields);
```

I could make:

```
Map<String, Object> dataModel = new HashMap<>();
dataModel.put("unit", unit);
```

and ftl designer would have possibility to access x, y and z of the unit somehow.

So I have got 2 questions regarding that:
1. How to make good access to the fields of `Unit` object in ftl file?
2. How can ftl designer know, what are the possible fields that he can use?

So far I have made point 1 to work with reflection. Unit class is implementing `TemplateHashModel` and in `get(String)` I made it to find field by name and then parse the value to `SimpleScalar`, `SimpleNumber` or other `TemplateHashModel`. Is it a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding question 1, that works like that by default. You just do `dataModel.put("unit", unit)`, where `unit` is a `Unit` object, and from the template `unit.x` and such should work. If it doesn't, then maybe `Unit` or the getter methods aren't public, or you are using some non-default restrictive `object_wrapper` configuration setting. (Or, maybe the problem is that `Unit` implements `Map` or `List` or some other interface that FreeMarker treats specially.)

Regarding question 2, the data model content is the contract between the template (MVC View) and the other parts of the system, so ideally, it has to be documented somewhere by you. Generating such documentation automatically is beyond FreeMarker, among others because the data-model content of a template might varies depending on various conditions, and thus in general it's not discoverable automatically. However, in some application the information could be generated from the Java classes (like `Unit`) of the variables. As of what top-level variables exist ("unit") and what their classes are, the data model itself can be a Java object of a template-specific class, rather than a `Map`, so then the whole data model is specified by the Java classes.